# Sync two Drupal sites with Drupal_sync module

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, deployment

I have two Drupal 7 sites: one, local dev portal (.0.101), and two, remote copy portal (.0.100), which in certain moment was desync. In both there new nodes and users creates, and in dev there are new modules and conf apply too.

I'm trying to use [Drupal Sync module](http://drupal.org/project/drupal_sync) (I reached it from [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32941/sync-content-between-two-drupal-sites)) to sync both, but don't work.

In remote copy, Drupal_sync complains about settings

> Drupal sync settings is wrong. Check settings and site domain here.

, but I revised it a dozen.

Settings (A=dev, B=remote copy):

Domain 1: (A) localhost; (B) localhost

Count http requests (if receive fail) * (A) 10; (B) 10

Frequency of updates * (A) 5 mins; (B) 5 mins

Could of updates per request * (B) 20 ; (B) 20

Sync entities: same marks on both machines.

Site remote: (A) mucharuina_qnap ; (B) local_maclobo

> URL: (A) http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs ; (B) http://192.168.0.101/drupal7

Login Same user for two sites.

Contraseña (Idem)

Choose term for sync rules (Idem)

I follow instruction in Drupal sync module but it don't work. After run initial setup, it "say" that there are changes to sync but it don't do.

I see this in register on B machine:

> Detalles
>
> Tipo drupal_sync
>
> Fecha Jueves, Agosto 1, 2013 - 17:57
>
> Usuario admin
>
> Ubicación http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/modules/list/confirm
>
> Referente http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/modules
>
> Mensaje Site: 192.168.0.100 has wrong settings.
>
> =============================================
>
> Operación: Update to remote site
>
> Gravedad aviso
>
> Nombre del servidor 192.168.0.101
>
> Operaciones

> Detalles
>
> Tipo drupal_sync_initial_setup_error
>
> Fecha Jueves, Agosto 1, 2013 - 18:09
>
> Usuario admin
>
> Ubicación 
>
> http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/config/drupal_sync/drupal_sync_ini...
>
> Referente 
>
> http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/config/drupal_sync/drupal_sync_ini...
>
> Mensaje
>
> local_maclobo
> 10
> Creación de un diario-e: motivación, intención y temática
> array (
> 8 => '¡Hola Mundo!',
> 10 => 'Creación de un diario-e: motivación, intención y temática',
> )
>
> Gravedad aviso
>
> Nombre del servidor 192.168.0.101
>
> Operaciones

Last, I can't see something in Sync Manager queue section, but relations section shows too much of them.

Anyone can help me with this module? Or, another way to sync two sites?

Thanks in advanced, and sorry for my poor english.

Best regards.

R. Gómez

Comment: Could you at least translate the error messages into English please? This is an English-only network, and questions that rely on foreign-language text will have to be closed I'm afraid. I'd also suggest that this is a bug report, and so needs to go to the module issue queue. Have you searched there first for similar issues?

Comment: Sorry about, here are:

Comment: Details

Type drupal_sync
Date Thursday, August 1, 2013 - 17:57
User admin
Location http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/modules/list/confirm
Concerning http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/modules
Site Message: 192.168.0.100 has wrong settings.

=============================================
Operation: Update to remote site
Level aviso
Server name 192.168.0.101
Operations

Comment: Type drupal_sync_initial_setup_error
Date Thursday, August 1, 2013 - 18:09
User admin
Location http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/config/drupal_sync/drupal_sync_ini...
Concerning http://192.168.0.100/drupal7_qs/admin/config/drupal_sync/drupal_sync_ini...
Message:
local_maclobo
10
(Blog entry title)
array (
8 => (Blog entry title)
10 => (Blog entry title),
)
Level aviso
Server name 192.168.0.101
Operations

Comment: And, yes, I revise bugs and issues on module page.

Comment: There are one issue likeness. I'll comment there. Thanks for your suggestion.