# How to implement a multi-themed site?

Tags: theming, multi-sites

I will soon start building a new reasonably large site, that will be presented to the end-user as several different sites. Different domains will map to different sections within the site, and will also have different themes.

How should I implement the "multi-theme"?

I'll be posting some ideas of my own, which I would love some feedback on, but would also very much like to hear other suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

I use the [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.  This allows me to give each area a distinct look without even touching any code.  It also integrates with the Print, Revisioning, Organic Groups, and other major modules out-of-the-box.

Some of the things this module enables you to do (from the module page):

> - individually-styled channels
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> - special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or role -specific themes
> - indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> - testing your redesign safely on a live server

Answer (score 1):

Implement several themes, possibly with a common base theme, and switch theme in code, such as suggested over here: [How do I change a theme based on the URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-do-i-change-a-theme-based-on-the-url)

Answer (score 1):

Implement a single theme, with all the different themes inside it, and stick a `class="name_of_sub_section"` onto the body element.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will fit your bill, but the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module may work for you.  With it, you can map different themes to different domains (the Domain Theme submodule) does this.  I haven't used it for theme switching, but I have use other features of the module with good success.

Another option is to use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module, possible with combination with [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta).  With this you can have different portions of your site mapped to different contexts, and then have various reactions associated with them.  I don't use this technique, but I have colleagues who do.